# oidc-client - signinredirect - doesn't redirect to redirect_uri

Tags: oidc-client-js

I'm using OIDC client and I'm calling below line to signin:

```
public signinRedirect(args?: any): Promise<any> {
    return this.oidcUserManager.signinRedirect(args);
}
```

After this it goes to ID server login page and after login I see it is calling below in network tab:

```
https://localhost:50000/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=xxxxx
```

And after this it calls URL:

```
https://localhost:50000/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2
```

It stays in ID server and doesn't redirect back to my SPA application with `redirect_url`.

Client configuration:

```
 private createUserManager(): UserManager {
      const authSettings: any = {
        authority: "https://localhost:50000/",
        clientId: "xxx.web.local",
        loginRedirect: "http://localhost:1436/callback",
        logoutRedirect: "http://localhost:1436/",
        scope: "openid profile roles email offline_access api",
        idleRefreshTime: 330

      }; // APP_CONFIG.authSettings;
        const oidcSettings = {
            authority: authSettings.authority,
            client_id: authSettings.clientId,
            redirect_uri: authSettings.loginRedirect,
            silent_redirect_uri: authSettings.loginRedirect + '-silent.html',
            post_logout_redirect_uri: authSettings.logoutRedirect,
            response_type: "id_token token",
            scope: authSettings.scope,
            automaticSilentRenew: false,
            accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: authSettings.idleRefreshTime,
            filterProtocolClaims: true,
            loadUserInfo: true,
        };

      return new this.window.Oidc.UserManager(oidcSettings);
```

ID server - Startup file

```
 var identityServer = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                if (authServerSettings.CookieLifetime.HasValue) options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, authServerSettings.CookieLifetime.Value, 0);
                if (authServerSettings.CookieSlidingExpiration.HasValue) options.Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration = authServerSettings.CookieSlidingExpiration.Value;

                //options.Authentication.de
                options.Authentication.CookieAuthenticationScheme = IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                options.Authentication.RequireCspFrameSrcForSignout = false;
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
               // options.UserInteraction.CustomRedirectReturnUrlParameter = "https://localhost:1430/callback1";
               
            })    
     var authentication = services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme);
```

logic to redirect to SPA in ID server after authentication

```
 var claims = new List<Claim>();
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
                    claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, user.Id));

                    // issue authentication cookie with subject ID and username
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims)));
```

Comment: I am sure somethings is missing in your config/code. Have you added redirect_uri settings in your configuration? Also paste complete code the way you are trying to authenticate and redirect. I want to see the flow

Comment: Added code above. In signin even tried giving default schema, still didnt work...not sure what's going on..

Comment: Is it your IDP server or you are using any of open source, also IDP is not redirecting to proper URI i think so. Check the URL
`https://localhost:50000/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2` instead IDP often sends back the redirect_uri query param in response

Comment: Im using openid connect. in return urll I see the configured redirect_uri.